# Explanation for php code with if statement

Tags: php, variables, if-statement

I have code like this can some one help me figure out how the condition logic work in this

```
$environment = ( $this->environment == "yes" ) ? 'TRUE' : 'FALSE';
    // Decide which URL to post to
      $environment_url = ( "FALSE" == $environment )
                               ? 'https://api.ewaypayments.com/AccessCodes'
               : 'https://api.sandbox.ewaypayments.com/AccessCodes';
```

Comment: Look up how the ternary operator works, [here's](https://davidwalsh.name/php-shorthand-if-else-ternary-operators) a useful link

Comment: just think an "if" in front of each "(", a "then" for each "?" and an "else" for each ":"

Comment: @IsmaelPadilla Thanks

Comment: @Jeff that makes it very easy thank you :). Maybe you can make it as an answer?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference — What does this symbol mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

Comment: Someone in your team really takes a lot of extra work to avoid [booleans](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php)

Answer (score 1):

You have two `ternary if statements`.  Although they look different than traditional if statements, they operate the same way.

Line by line -- This is how this code works:

```
$environment = ( $this->environment == "yes" ) ? 'TRUE' : 'FALSE';
```

This is the exact same as

```
if($this->environment == "yes"){
    $environment = 'TRUE';
}else{
    $environment = 'FALSE';
}
```

So now `$environment` has been set.  Onto the next **ternary if**

```
$environment_url = ( "FALSE" == $environment )
    ? 'https://api.ewaypayments.com/AccessCodes'
    : 'https://api.sandbox.ewaypayments.com/AccessCodes';
```

This is the exact same as this if:

```
if ($environment == 'FALSE'){
    $environment_url = 'https://api.ewaypayments.com/AccessCodes';
}else{
    $environment_url = 'https://api.sandbox.ewaypayments.com/AccessCodes';
}
```

The `?` in the statement indicates to `php` that this is a `ternary` conditional. The `condition` on the left side of the `:` is what happens if the `statement` returns "positive".  The `condition` on the right side is what happens if the `statement` returns "negative".

Answer (score 0):

Just think an "if" in front of each `(`, a "then" for each `?` and an "else" for each `:`

It's called [tenary operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary)